# How to integrate wkhtmltopdf into my java webapplication?

Tags: java, wkhtmltopdf, html-to-pdf

I am trying to generate PDF document from HTML using `wkhtmltopdf`. But I am not able to figure out how to integrate `wkhtmltopdf`  into my webapplication as there are no `jar` files in the `tar` file provided by the author. Can someone help me to set up this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The wkhtmltopdf program is provided in a form of a stand-alone executable. It uses [Qt Webkit module](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtwebkit.html) from Qt library for rendering the HTML and producing the PDF output. It is written in C/C++ thus you will be unable to find any JAR files.

You can save the HTML to a temporary file, use Runtime.exec() or ProcessBuilder to fork a new process from Java and when the process finishes, read the PDF file.

Qt Jambi might help you as well with its [QWebView](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtjambi-4.5.2_01/com/trolltech/qt/webkit/QWebView.html) class might help you as well. Alternatively, you can implement your own wrapper over Qt Webkit in C and create Java bindings using JNI for calling it from Java in-process.

Depending on the target environment, you have to assess if you can afford forking processes from Java or implementing native calls as it might be a possible security risk.